# Using namespace and including a library

Tags: php, namespaces

I just installed memcache on my xampp but I'm having trouble including it to a file of mine that uses namespaces.

How do I have to call it to get it to work under my namespace? I only tried doing:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
```

But it says:

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Test\Memcache' not found in x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use fully qualified name like this:

```
$memcache = new \Memcache;
```